# React.js - Is it acceptable to create a variable in the window object for sharing it across components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, redux, global

Is it acceptable to create a global object on `window` for variables, objects, properties, and methods needed across components,?

It seems to me a simple, easy, and direct approach. As long as everyone working on the project is aware of this global object, it is safe.

Regarding cross-component access, I've looked at:

- **Prop Drilling** [1]. Tedious and prone to error. considered bad practice by some.
- **Redux** [2]. Good for larger projects, but can get involved.
- **Context** [3]. Also a bit of a pain. Seemingly just another way to create a global, with more overhead.

I know that globals are often viewed like the metric system in the USA: Evil and from the Devil. The reason is that programmers can step on each other... call to mind the classic `foo` `bar` example, where everyone loves to use these variables in the global scope, and their values are overwritten. However, I think it's safe as long as the global class is named for minimal conflicts, and other developers on the project are aware of its use.

Given the contortions from other global state systems, I think that this might be a valid use case.

**Complete, Minimal, Verifiable Example**

Note how we hang a couple variables, an array, a `Cheese` object with properties and getter/setter methods.

```
class Cheese {
  constructor(brand, type) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.type = type
  }
  getBrand() { return this.brand; }
  setBrand(b) { this.brand =b; return 0; }
}

window.myGlobal = {}
window.myGlobal["swiss"] = new Cheese("Jarlsberg", "Swiss")
window.myGlobal["cheese"] = ["Swiss", "Cheddar", "Brie"]
window.myGlobal["version"] = "0.1.5"
```

...and when we need something from a component:

```
console.log(window.myGlobal.swiss.getBrand()) //-> "Swiss"
console.log(window.myGlobal.cheese[1]) //-> "Cheddar"
console.log(window.myGlobal.version) //-> "0.1.5"
```

References:

1. https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling
2. https://redux.js.org/
3. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: The main problem with that would be that you can't (easily) re-render components when the values change. If Redux seems too involved, MobX is a light-weight alternative.

Comment: In this case, you can't rerender your component when something changes.

if you don't need to rerender it you can just create additional helper file and import what you want when you want)

But for small cases, Context is simple and can do what you want

Answer (score 3):

With window global variables you cannot track your variable state and it's not reactive (the component doesn't listen to its changes), also these variables are not safe and they could be mutated outside the components for example the user could open the browser console and set other values to your variables.

From [Vuex official docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) (the equivalent of Redux in Vue.js) they say:

> So why don't we extract the shared state out of the components, and manage it in a global singleton? With this, our component tree becomes a big "view", and any component can access the state or trigger actions, no matter where they are in the tree!
> By defining and separating the concepts involved in state management and enforcing rules that maintain independence between views and states, we give our code more structure and maintainability.

They mean by global singleton a class instantiated once and access it fields and methods from the whole app like window .